# how to load models from another module in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework

i am developing an application using zend framework.

i have two modules, admin and default, and each of them has their specific model directory.

i want to know, if i can instantiate a model in admin module from within default module and if this approach has problem regarding to the MVC model.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

So long as youve set up the `Zend_Application_Resource_Modules` or something pretty equivalent all you models should be registerd with the autoloader via the `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` that the modules resources registers. **In short, if you follow the default way of doing things, then Models from all modules will be set up for Autoloading in the bootstrap phase.**

About [Zend Application and Resources](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can call get_class(): https://www.php.net/get_class

There's possibly a more *zend like* way to do it, but I don't know. Check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

What about call via object?
Like inter-connect two model functions in controller.

$contacts = new Model_DbTable_Contactsmdl(); // Model file in contact module

$update_id = $contacts->updateContacts($cn_id', $responsearray);

This code inside my syncController.

So you can handle admin / model function in default / controller.